# To change the path of libprotobuf.a library from /lib64/ to /usr/local/lib

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

With the gRPC installed, I have libprotobuf.a in the lib64/ folder. But I want the libprotobuf.a library to be used from /usr/local/lib.
I tried changing the libprotobuf path as shown here in the /lib64/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-targets-noconfig.cmake  file.

```
# Import target "protobuf::libprotobuf" for configuration ""
set_property(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS NOCONFIG)
set_target_properties(protobuf::libprotobuf PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_NOCONFIG "CXX"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS protobuf::libprotobuf )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_protobuf::libprotobuf "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a" )
```

But I get the following error while building grpc program :

```
[root@9fe88e5146c1 build]# cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$MY_INSTALL_DIR ../..
-- Found Protobuf: /bin/protoc-3.15.2.0 (found version "3.15.2.0")
-- Using protobuf 3.15.2.0
-- Using gRPC 1.37.1
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:153 (add_executable):
  Target "server" links to target "protobuf::/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:153 (add_executable):
  Target "client" links to target "protobuf::/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf" but
  the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

**Can anyone please say what all changes to be done in the CMakelists.txt  and   *.cmake files ?**
Thank you!!

Comment: What does your CMakeLists.txt look like? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67590176/edit) it into your question.

Comment: `protobuf::/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf` - what happened here??